# WebAuthenticationBroker Issues

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-8.1

I having some issues with the data being returned by the WebAuthenticationBroker in my app. The api I'm connecting to utilizes OAuth 1.0a. I'm able to get the Broker to pull up the authorization page, but ResponseData from the Broker is just url to the page that contains the key value pair for the OAuth Verifier. So I tried a web request to try and get that data, but end up getting 405: Method Not allowed error from the page. Here is my code...

```
public async Task Authorize(string oAuthAuthorizeUrl)
{
    // Start WebAuthenticationBroker
    System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(oAuthAuthorizeUrl);
    System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(oAuthCallBack);

    WebAuthenticationResult auth = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartUri, EndUri);

    if (auth.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(auth.ResponseData);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        string responseText = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        string oauth_verifier = null;
        string[] keyValPairs = responseText.Split('&');

        for (int i = 0; i < keyValPairs.Length; i++)
        {
            String[] splits = keyValPairs[i].Split('=');
            switch (splits[0])
            {
                case "oauth_verifier":
                    oauth_verifier = splits[1];
                    break;
            }
        }

        oAuthVerifier = oauth_verifier;
     }
}
```

is this how the Broker is supposed to work? I assumed it would send back the data with the Verifier. Thanks for the help.